# Badges from other sites

Tags: discussion, design, badges

Seeing music note badges for WorldBuilding and CodeGolf just strikes me as odd.

[image: Music Notes for Other Sites]

Is it possible to have regular badges for these other sites and keep music badges just on posts related to this stack? Or even make this menu use the standard badges?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a network-wide issue.  Support this feature request on Meta.StackExchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233517/154510

Comment: @MatthewRead This would be considered [tag:status-bydesign]. It's an idea that's been considered but not one that we're actively exploring that this time.

Comment: @Hynes - thanks for the info. This is the first site I've been on with custom badges, so I was wondering if it was a `bug` or `bydesign`. Thus the `discussion` tag.